# how to extracting a part of an expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression

i want to simplify code to add loadoptions and association filtering so i created this class.

```
class GraphQuery<T>
{
    private IQueryable<T> query;
    private DataLoadOptions load;

    public GraphQuery(DataLoadOptions load, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        this.load = load;
        this.query = query;
    }

    public GraphQuery<T> Load(
            Expression<Func<T, object>> expr, 
            Expression<Func<T, object>> filter)
    {
        load.LoadWith(expr);
        load.AssociateWith(filter);
        return this;
    }

    // more public methods ...
}
```

it can then be used like this:

```
var clients = Graph(db.Clients.Where(e => !e.Deleted))
    .Load(e => e.ClientPersons, 
        e => e.ClientPersons.Where(j => !j.Person.Deleted));
```

however, i see a very simple repetition of `e => e.ClientPersons`. so i would like to reduce the above usage to :

```
var clients = Graph(db.Clients.Where(e => !e.Deleted))
    .Load(e => e.ClientPersons.Where(j => !j.Person.Deleted));
```

so the Load function should look something like

```
    public GraphQuery<T> Load(Expression<Func<T, object>> filter)
    {
        var expr = ... extract first part of the expression that represents the association property
        load.LoadWith(expr);
        load.AssociateWith(filter);
        return this;
    }
```

i have never worked with linq expressions except for using them in queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the debugger to see what i could get from the expression and found it rather simple to extract what i needed. i guess its not pretty, but it gets the job done. if anybody has some recommendations to improve this - please post a comment.

```
    private static LambdaExpression GetRootMemberExpression(LambdaExpression lambda1)
    {
        var expr = lambda1.Body;
        while (!FindRoot(ref expr)) ;
        if (!(expr is MemberExpression))
            throw new Exception("MemberExpression required");
        return Expression.Lambda(expr, (expr as MemberExpression).Expression as ParameterExpression);
    }


    private static bool FindRoot(ref Expression expr)
    {
        if (expr is MemberExpression)
            return FindRoot(ref expr, (expr as MemberExpression).Expression);
        if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
            return FindRoot(ref expr, (expr as MethodCallExpression).Object);
        throw new Exception("Unexpected Expression type encountered (" + expr.NodeType + ")");
    }

    private static bool FindRoot(ref Expression expr, Expression expr2)
    {
        if (expr2.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
            return true;
        expr = expr2;
        return false;
    }
```